# Having trouble with cin

Tags: c++

```
cout << "It is your turn " << name << endl;
cout << "Please type the piece you want to move in this form: x,y" << endl;
int xSrc, ySrc;
char buffer[4];
buffer[3] = '\0';

//Check input
try {
    cin >> buffer;
    cin.get(buffer, 4);
    cout << std::cin.gcount() << " characters read: " << buffer << '\n';
    xSrc = buffer[0];
    ySrc = buffer[2];
    cout << "What u wrote:" << xSrc << " " << ySrc << endl;

    if (cin.fail()) {
        cin.clear();
        throw "Your input isn't formatted correctly:";
    }
}
```

I am creating a chess game. The player enters the coordinates of where they want to move their chess piece the following way: 2,2

For some reason, my buffer isn't getting the first 2. The buffer only contains ,2

Why is this happening?

Comment: `cin.get(buffer, 4)` is overwriting what `cin >> buffer` did

Comment: You might want to check `cin.fail` before assigning to `xSrc` and `ySrc`. In any case, you should probably do your own validation of the string in `buffer` before assigning random characters that the user passed in to `xSrc` and `ySrc`.

Comment: Note that `xSrc` and `ySrc` will not contain the numbers of the pieces, they will contain the ASCII character codes for those numbers.

Comment: Okay. Thanks that worked. Do you know cin.gcount() says 0 characters were read still?

Comment: After using `cin >> buffer` it read `2,2`. Then `cin.get(buffer, 4)` reads 0 characters before the newline.

Comment: Also does cin >> buffer ignore anything greater than 4 characters or does still contain all extra characters? Does cin.clear() get read of the extra characters?

Comment: `cin >> buffer` reads everything up to the next whitespace, no matter how long it is.

Comment: Right so where do the extra characters go since they don't fit in the buffer?

Comment: They overwrite the memory outside the buffer, causing undefined behavior.

Comment: Use `std::string` so you don't have to worry about problems like that.

Comment: so how do i avoid this if i want to use the char array? I'll use string but I am just curious.

Comment: Yes, you can use the `get` function. But why did you use `>>` also?

Comment: So get function would prevent the buffer overflow?

Comment: @BenjaminErichsen Yes. Read the [docs](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/get/) for `istream::get`. The second parameter is the maximum number of characters to write.

Comment: Thank you everyone for your help!!